Is this morphism finite
Let $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$ be morphisms of projective schemes such that

$f$ is finite;
$g$ is surjective;
$\dim Y = \dim Z$; and
$g \circ f$ is finite.

Is $g$ finite in this case? I'm really lost and don't seem to know how to start.

Since everything in sight is projective, finite is the same as quasi-finite (i.e. finite fibres). Since $g \circ f$ is finite, it is quasi-finite, so
$g$ is quasi-finite, hence finite.

Could you please elaborate on "$g\circ f$ is quasi-finite, so $g$ is quasi-finite"? I'm more familiar with properties passing from $g\circ f$ to $f$ (not $g$), e.g. Lemma 035D in the Stacks Project.

If there were a point $p \in Z$ such that $g^{-1}(p)$ is infinite, then $(g \circ f)^{-1}(p)$ would be infinite too.
